# Silverlight and RX: Why I have to resize the Browser to update the UI?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, user-interface, synchronization, system.reactive

Let's start from the beginning:

I'm writing an algorithm for a Silverlight application, which has to do go through a lot different combinations of a high complexity to find an optimum. To give the algorithm the possibility to use all given resources on the client, I decided to do provide a parallel version.

Firstly I wrote my own async event-orientated scheduler class with a wait handle and a blocking object to limit the amount of parallel threads and to wait for all threads at the end, until I fired the final CalculationCompletedEvent (by the way: I was using Backgroundworkers to perform the multithreading). But something there wasn’t thread safe, and the amount of returning elements in the result list wasn’t constant. I considered not to spend more time in searching for the leak after a colleague pointed me on the Reactive Extensions (rx).

To get an idea of how to use this, I combined an [consumer-producer example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/7d10d73c-321c-446e-8b6d-b81ee8d9b314/producerconsumer-queue-and-blockingcollection-in-c-40.aspx) with some advices on how to use rx ([example1](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-Reactive-Extensions-in-Silverlight.aspx) and [example2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/655b80f6-f487-42a0-a5c8-18222ed95f54)).

This works great, but what I don’t understand is: Why do I have to resize the browser to have the listbox updated and show the containing elements of “_receivedStrings”? Once again a tiny stupid neglect?

By the way: If you wouldn’t recommend using the rx, give a shot and tell me why and what to use else.

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ReactiveTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listBox1" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Klick me!" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ReactiveTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private int _parallelThreadsAmount;

        public IList<String> receivedStrings;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            receivedStrings = 
                new List<String>();
            this._parallelThreadsAmount = 10;

            this.listBox1.DataContext = receivedStrings;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IList<IObservable<String>> obsCollection = 
                new List<IObservable<String>>();

            foreach (var item in forums)
            {
                obsCollection.Add(Calculate(item));
            }
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            obsCollection.Merge(this._parallelThreadsAmount)
                .Subscribe(
                    y =>
                    {
                        receivedStrings.Add(
                            String.Format("{0} - Received: {1}", receivedStrings.Count, y));
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan elapsed = end - start;
                        this.receivedStrings.Add(
                            String.Format(
                                "{0}/{1} done in {2} ms.", 
                                receivedStrings.Count, 
                                forums.Count(), 
                                elapsed.TotalSeconds)
                            );
                    }
                );
        }

        IObservable<String> Calculate(String source)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            return Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                // simulate some work, taking different time, 
                // to get the threads end in an other order than they've been started                
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(500, 2000));
                return source;
            }));
        }


        static readonly String[] forums = new string[]
        {
            "announce",
            "whatforum",
            "reportabug",
            "suggest",
            "Offtopic",
            "msdnsandbox",
            "netfxsetup",
            "netfxbcl",
            "wpf",
            "regexp",
            "msbuild",
            "netfxjscript",
            "clr",
            "netfxtoolsdev",
            "asmxandxml",
            "netfx64bit",
            "netfxremoting",
            "netfxnetcom",
            "MEFramework",
            "ncl",
            "wcf",
            "Geneva",
            "MSWinWebChart",
            "dublin",
            "oslo",
            // … some more elements
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoreing the lack of MVVM, IoC, Testability etc...
You dont implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you are not using ObservableCollection(of T). 
 1. Change your public field to a pubilc readonly property
 2. Use ObservableCollection instead of IList

```
//public IList<String> receivedStrings; 
private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _receivedStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> ReceivedStrings
{
    get { return _receivedStrings;}
}
```

you may also have to use the ObserveOnDispatcher() to ensure that you are called back on the Dispatcher, as you cant update the UI (even via Binding) on a thread that is not the Dispatcher's thread.

```
obsCollection.Merge(this._parallelThreadsAmount)                 
  .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher)
  //-or-.ObserveOnDispatcher()
  //-or even better -.ObserveOn(_schedulerProvider.Dispatcher)
  .Subscribe(
```

Comment: Thank you Lee. I'm obviously new in this business and up to now I did not use UI a lot. But I'm trying to get step by step to MVVM. You helped me getting an other small step closer. This has to be enough for today, because it's just additionally :)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I'm tempted to say that you are a bit confused with Rx, which is quite normal to be honest :)

As Lee Campbell writes there is a few things for starters, the resizing issue is not related to Rx at all as I see it but it's the ObservableCollection stuff.

Besides that I have modified your code a bit to handle some of the things I see, I'm not sure if it is exactly what you want since you have a specific assignment of how parallel you want stuff, but I'm gonna be bold and say it's not your concern (and hopefully I'm not being a smartass here).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //extension method in Rx for wrapping
    var obsCollection = forums.ToObservable();

    //Observing on the dispatcher to prevent x-thread exceptions
    obsCollection.Select( Calculate ).ObserverOnDispatcher().Subscribe(
        receivedString => { 
                receivedStrings.Add( String.Format("{0} - Received: {1}", receivedStrings.Count, y) );
            },
            ()=>{
                DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan elapsed = end - start;
                this.receivedStrings.Add(
                    String.Format( "{0}/{1} done in {2} ms.", receivedStrings.Count, forums.Count(), elapsed.TotalSeconds)
                );
            }
    );
}

Random rand = new Random();
IObservable<string> Calculate(string inputString)
{
    //launching the "calculation" on the taskpool...can be changed to other schedulers
    return Observable.Start(
        ()=>{
            Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(150,250));

            return inputString;
            }, Scheduler.ThreadPool
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks cyberzed, this is really intersting and educational. I will try to use this approach in my future exercices. With the point about "how many parallel threads" you're rigth. I ported it from my first implementation where I started a number of backgroundworker, blocked the producer until all of them finished, checked something and then decided if to cancel because I already got, what I was searching for or start an other bunch of backgroundworker. But in this case it would be better to just take a given number of elements from the array and don't care about mergeing, right?

Comment: I looked a bit at it and in the case where you want to have control of the amount of parallelism, you might wanna look at combining it with the TPL (can't remember which SL version it's available in) - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/12d3f79a-0a53-4854-976e-5fa0d86f01ee

Comment: You're right. Now I'm using TPL. Using tasks seem to better since you let the OS (or what ever) choose if threads are neccessary or not. It's easy to use to syncronize each x-times. Helped me a lot :) thanks again

Comment: No problem :) we are all here to help out